# I have problems displaying data with Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

how you doing, i've been working on this for 2 hours now and I can't seem to get my page to dynamically display information when I change it. Would appreciate if someone can tell me what went wrong.

This is my HTML

```
<h2>Feedbacks</h2>
<form>
<select onchange="viewFeedback(this.value);">
    <option value="unread">View Unread</option>
    <option value="all" >View All</option>
</select>
</form>
<div id="feedbackview"></div>
```

This is my ajax

```
function createObject() {
var request_type;
var browser = navigator.appName;
if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
    request_type = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}else{
    request_type = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
return request_type;

}
var http = createObject();
function viewFeedback(condition) { 
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(http.readyState == 4) {
            document.getElementById('feedbackview').innerHTML=http.responseText;
        }
        http.open("GET",'viewfeedback.php?condition='+condition,true);
        http.send(null);
    }   
 }
```

and here is the php

```
$condition = $_GET['condition'];
$db = new db();

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM feedback");
$rows = $db->countRows($query);
if($rows != 0) {
    $results = $db->getRows($query);
    foreach($results as $result) {
        extract($result);
        echo $name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I don't know if that Ajax creation function is so great. I would comment it out for now and add it back only if it is not working in a supported browser. Instead just do this:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Next, try hitting the PHP web service directly in your browser. Is it working? If so, fix the issues in your Ajax request:

```
function viewFeedback(condition) {
    http.open("GET", 'viewfeedback.php?condition=' + condition, true);
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (http.readyState == 4) {
            if (http.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById('feedbackview').innerHTML = http.responseText;
            } else {
                console.log(http.response);
            }
        }
    }
    http.send(null);
}
```

Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: Well, it worked perfect. I had to change some things in it but it was great. Thank you! =)

Answer (score 1):

The `open()` and `send()` calls should not be within the `onreadystatechange` event, move them outside. You can also move the event outside from the `viewFeedback()` too because there's no need to keep re-defining it every time your dropdown is changed.

```
var http = createObject();
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4) {
        document.getElementById('feedbackview').innerHTML=http.responseText;
    }
}
function viewFeedback(condition) { 

    http.open("GET",'viewfeedback.php?condition='+condition,true);
    http.send(null);
 }
```

Also note that you don't do anything with `$_GET['condition']` on the PHP side, so the response will always be the same regardless of which dropdown item is selected.

Comment: ...or event better - just move to using jQuery for your AJAX calls.